# How to un-italicise Bulletpoints

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize

```
\begin{proposition}

An elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation

\begin{itemize}    
\item[(a)]{is nonsingular iff $\Delta_E\neq0$.}   
\item[(b)]{has a node iff $\Delta_E=0$ and $c_4\neq0$.    
\item[(c)]{has a cusp iff $\Delta_E=c_4=0$.}   
\end{itemize}
\end{proposition}
```

Because this is written as a proposition, all the text is italicised. At the same time, so are the bullet points (a),(b),(c). What do I do to remove the italics on the bullet points but still keep the text italicised as per normal.

When it is written as a definition, there isn't a problem as the original text in the definition is not italicised.

Comment: You could use the `enumitem` package, an `enumerate` environment with `label=\normalfont(\alph*)` passed in the optional argument.

Comment: Where do people get the idea that they should use `\item[(a) ]`. I've seen several use this lately so I'd like to know where the idea comes from so we can get that idea fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}
An elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\normalfont(\alph{enumi})}
\item is nonsingular iff $\Delta_E\neq0$.
\item has a node iff $\Delta_E=0$ and $c_4\neq0$.
\item  has a cusp iff $\Delta_E=c_4=0$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

Now the labeling is automatic. If you move the redefinition of `\labelenumi` to the preamble it will affect all first level (i.e. not nested) enumerate environments.

[image: enum]

Comment: What would I put if I want the numbering to be in numerals instead? :)

Comment: For Roman numerals, change `\alph` to `\roman` or `\Roman`. For arabic numerals (1,2,...) use `\arabic`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newenvironment{conditions}[1][\alph]
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(#1*)]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
An elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation
\begin{conditions}
\item is nonsingular iff $\Delta_E\neq0$.
\item has a node iff $\Delta_E=0$ and $c_4\neq0$.
\item  has a cusp iff $\Delta_E=c_4=0$.
\end{conditions}
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
The following conditions are equivalent:
\begin{conditions}[\arabic]
\item pigs can fly,
\item donkeys have short ears,
\item the moon is made of Swiss cheese.
\end{conditions}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does \upshape do?

Comment: @HaikalYeo It's the command for telling LaTeX to use the upright font.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the `itemize` environment for a `enumerate` one. Then we personalize this particular environment just to not interfere with other enumerate environtments. Just like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}


\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}

An elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation

\begin{enumerate} [label=\rmfamily\emph{(\alph*)}]  
\item   {is nonsingular iff $\Delta_E\neq0$.}   
\item   {has a node iff $\Delta_E=0$ and $c_4\neq0$}.    
\item   {has a cusp iff $\Delta_E=c_4=0$.}   
\end{enumerate}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

The label part do the work, leaving the changes just for this environment. The result is this:

[image]